# No Such Column on Entity Error

Tags: error-messages

I'm working on integrating Click and Pledge for a client. I am by no means a SF developer but have more than decent admin skills. I keep getting this error - "No such column 'MiddleName' on entity 'Contact'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Since I'm a rookie. I have NO idea where to even begin looking. Eager to learn how to fix this error. Any ideas? Since Click and Pledge is a managed package I'm unsure of what aspects I can actually edit or if I need to submit a ticket to them.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When do you get that message?  Are you trying to save a Visualforce page, an object, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Click and Pledge. It may be have a custom field called MiddleName__c. Try appending the __c to the end of the field in your code. This is the API name of the field. You can check the API name in Setup under the custom fields section for the Contact object.

Another alternative is that MiddleName is a field on the Contact object that is in beta . See https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm for a list of all Contact fields. If that's the case, then you will need to contact support to enable it in your org.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to this known issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0tvAAC

We have seen the describe call return all the fields available in the latest API version when called from a class marked with an earlier API version.

Move your classes to the latest API version so what the describe call returns and what is acceptable in the query are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I ran across this when researching the same problem. For our org, we had the fields enabled and set to visible under the user interface settings. I was still unable to access through the API, yet I was able to through the Developer Console.

I am new to Salesforce as well, and when going through the training documentation the API version in the examples is set to v20.0. To access the middleName and suffix attributes, the API version needs to be set to v31.0 or later, such as:

```
https://yourDomain.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/
```

More info can be found at the [Salesforce knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-is-the-Middle-Name-Field-not-Available-when-Exporting-Contacts-Leads-Person-Accounts-or-Users-using-DataLoader&language=en_US&type=1).